# read the settings of a office add-in manifest file from the angular app which is inside the Excel task pane

Tags: excel, angular, office365, office-js, office-js-helpers

**Requirement:** Read the **AutoConfig** element in a manifest file using office.js/angular app and will
hide/show the content in my angular app in task pane based on the AutoConfig value.

**The 1st approach** I will put a custom tag i.e `<AutoConfig>true</AutoConfig>`
in the manifest file and this custom tag should read by the angular app/office.js in the task pane.

**The 2nd approach** will pass the URL parameter from the`<SourceLocation https://localhost:3000/index.html?autoConfig=true>` if it is not possible to give a custom tag in the manifest file (1st approach)

could you please help me how can I achieve this requirement?

Comment: Can you explain your scenario a bit better? Rick's answer sums it up, what you want (reading from the manifest) is not possible, but there might be another way of solving your problem.

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid that there is no way at present for an Office Add-in to read its own manifest. But you can vote for the same idea at [Create an API for reading resource strings and URLs from the add-in manifest](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/34781983-create-an-api-for-reading-resource-strings-and-url).